# Android Clang mips/mips64 assembler error "unable to execute command: program not executable"

Tags: android-ndk, clang, mips

I am attempting to compile a C source file with the following command (Windows x64):

```
E:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang -target mipsel-none-linux-android -gcc-toolchain E:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -D__android__ --sysroot=E:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-24/arch-mips -o "C:/array.o" -c "C:/array.c"
```

Every time I get the error:

```
clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang.exe: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have verified that the folders and required binaries exist (my NDK install is from the Android SDK itself).

I also have the exact same problem on macOS, but with additional output where the "program not executable" error occurs:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-march'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mabi'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-call_nonpic'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-KPIC'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'mips32r2'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '32'
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

-v shows the following (on both Windows x64 and macOS, with macOS calling "/usr/bin/as"):

```
Android clang version 3.8.256229  (based on LLVM 3.8.256229)
Target: mipsel-none-linux-android
Thread model: posix
...
clang -cc1 version 3.8.256229 based upon LLVM 3.8.256229 default target x86_64-unknown-linux
...
"as" -march mips32r2 -mabi 32 -call_nonpic -EL -KPIC
```

With the ellipses being path output (all verified to be correct) - to reiterate this same problem happens on both Windows x64 and macOS.

---

Every other supported Android NDK architecture works perfectly fine with this command (swapping the paths and -target for the other architectures). i686, x86_64, aarch64, armv5te, armv6 and armv7-a all work on both Windows x64 and macOS.

I have also tried all combinations of quotes/no-quotes around the paths - no difference is made.

---

This problem occurs for me with mips, mips64, mipsel and mips64el.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -gcc-toolchain E:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64

GCC toolchain needs to point at a GCC toolchain, not Clang. I don't know why any of the other architectures are working. Possibly Clang is using the builtin assembler, but that still doesn't explain where it's getting its linker...

You might be interested in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/standalone_toolchain.md. It will handle the details of making sure the compilers can be correctly used directly like this.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It is very strange that it works for other architectures, especially in different environments. I suppose that is why I missed this.